# To produce an output like - m3g2k3c2 for an input mmmggkkkcc

Tags: java

So basically I want to show how many times a character repeats itself in a string, So if I have hheerrrtt , I should output it as h2e2r3t2, Here is what I tried:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HelloWorld{
static void process(String s){

int[] count = new int[10];

char[] array = s.toCharArray();

System.out.println(s.length());

     int j=0;
     int m=0;
     int i=0;
     char c;
     ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
     for(j=0;j<s.length();j++){

         m=0;
         for(i=0;i<s.length();i++){

                 if(array[j]==array[i]){
                     m++;
                 }

            }
            System.out.println("char "+ array[j] + " is " + m);
            list.add(array[j]);
            //c=char(m);
            list.add(Character(m)); // gives an error, can't be donethis way

     }


 }
     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
          process("hhhelloc");
     }
}
```

I am able to loop through each character and see how many times it repeated , but I am not able to generate a string like h3e1l2o1c1. I choose array list of characters and try adding each character followed by number of times it repeats but I am not able to add an integer to the arraylist. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println(list);` at the end of your process method, what does that output? It looks like you're making a list but never outputting it, which explains why you're not outputting anything.

Comment: Can't add an integer to arraylist like this- list.add(Character(m));

Comment: Maybe you need a `List` of something other than `Character`s. Maybe of `String`? Or just a `String` with no `List` at all.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're assuming m will always be smaller than 10. What if a character repeats more than 10 times? Converting an integer to a char doesn't work the way you want it to work.

Secondly, you don't need to pass over the array twice, it can be done in a single loop. Check the code below:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    private static void process( String s)
    {
        if( s == null || s.length() < 1)
            return;

        char[] array = s.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        char lastChar = array[0];
        int count = 1;

        for( int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if( array[i] == lastChar)
                ++count;
            else
            {
                builder.append( lastChar);
                builder.append( count);

                lastChar = array[i];
                count = 1;
            }
        }

        if( count > 0)
        {
            builder.append( lastChar);
            builder.append( count);
        }

        System.out.println( builder.toString());
    }

    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        process("hhhelloc");
    }
}
```